# Wordpress. display:none, дополнительные стили CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как скрыть или убрать class в дополнительных стилях СSS. Если можно, то объясните по какому принцепу это работает? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Полями в форме комментариев можно полностью управлять через фильтр [comment_form_default_fields](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/comment_form_default_fields)

Если нужно удалить именно поле, которое выделили на скриншоте, то можно это сделать вставив в functions.php следующий код

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'comment_form_hide_cookies_consent' );
function comment_form_hide_cookies_consent( $fields ) {
    unset( $fields['cookies'] );
    return $fields;
}
```

В этом же фильтре Вы можете переопределить отображение остальных полей

```
function modify_comment_form_fields($fields){
    $fields['author'] = '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<input id="author" placeholder="Your Name (No Keywords)" name="author" type="text" value="' .
                esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />'.
                '<label for="author">' . __( 'Your Name' ) . '</label> ' .
                ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' )  .
                '</p>';
    $fields['email'] = '<p class="comment-form-email">' . '<input id="email" placeholder="your-real-email@example.com" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
                '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />'  .
                '<label for="email">' . __( 'Your Email' ) . '</label> ' .
                ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) 
                 .
                '</p>';
    $fields['url'] = '<p class="comment-form-url">' .
             '<input id="url" name="url" placeholder="http://your-site-name.com" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /> ' .
            '<label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'domainreference' ) . '</label>' .
               '</p>';
    
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','modify_comment_form_fields');
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я вставил код для удаления конкретного поля в functions.php, очистил кэш, но у меня всё равно поле не убралось, в чём может быть проблема?